# Set culture from a controller's action

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

I try to create a CMS for which I have to set the Culture Info depending on the language selection for a specific page. The only way to set the current language is the following:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("el-GR");
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("el-GR");
```

I tried to use these lines in the following locations:

- **Action :** It does not work. For some reason they do not change the Culture.
- **View :** It changes the culture but I will have to ask the user to type himself these lines in each view that he/she creates which is not a good idea.
- **_Layout.cshtml :** It does not work.

The best solution to my problem would be to set the culture in the action (I have one action which handles all the CMS requests) but in case that this is not possible it would be helpful to find a way to set the culture in the _Layout.cshtml file.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this link [Globalization and localization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2).
there many ways to do that

> > Implement a strategy to select the language/culture for each request
>
> 1. Localization middleware
> 2. QueryStringRequestCultureProvider
> 3. The Accept-Language HTTP header
> 4. Use a custom provider

Comment: These methods can not be used for my problem. I use the following route attribute **[Route("{*UrlParts}")]** which has as a result to get all the requests. From the UrlParts I get the address that the visitor requested and using the address I find the database contents that I have to display. When I find the content, this content information will inform me about the language that I have to set for the current request. This means that I have somehow to set the current language inside this action.